# USB thumbdrive reported speed difference between NTFS and FAT32

Tags: usb, filesystems, ntfs, speed, fat32

I found this rather strange. I have a USB 3.0 thumdrive (ADATA UV128/16GB), which when formatted as NTFS, seems to report a much higher writing speed than when formatted as FAT32. For example, I copied a 2 GB file from my hard disk to the thumbdrive, and the reported speeds are depicted below for NTFS and FAT32 in that order (Windows 7 Pro). The time for the FAT32 copying seems to be approximately the same. I am not sure if the FAT32 option is much slower or not as the progress dialog box disappears right away without a summary.

I noticed similar phenomena under other versions of windows as well, and for a while I have used NTFS exclusively because of the long time estimates reported for FAT32. Also, I bought several of these thumbdrives, and they all seem to behave the same way.

I don't know if anyone has noticed a similar phenomenon, or knows why this may happen?

[image: NTFS]

[image: FAT32]

Comment: Copy dialog is hardly a good way to test. Use a proper benchmark utility to compare, such as [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com).